# Cannot login LDAP users

Tags: linux, authentication, server, ldap, admin

I'm a LDAP noob, so please be gentle with me ;)

I want to setup an OpenLDAP server (dockerized), to authenticate various services with, the first one being Gogs. My current tree looks like this:

```
dc=domain,dc=tld
  ->cn=admin
  ->ou=applications
    ->cn=gogs
  ->ou=employees
    ->cn=testUser
```

I configured everything in the Gogs interface (binds to `cn=gogs,ou=applications,dc=domain,dc=tld`, using correct password), which searches for users to authenticate in `ou=employees,dc=domain,dc=tld`, which it has access to (I tried everything, even `olcAccess:{0}to * by * write`, out of sheer frustration).

However, login still fails. Even trying to run: `docker exec -it test-ldap ldapsearch -H ldap:// -b "cn=testUser,ou=employees,dc=domain,dc=tld" -D "cn=testUser,ou=employees,dc=domain,dc=tld" -w test` (test is the testUser's password, I confirmed plenty times), yields in this output:

```
  ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

I have absolutely no idea of what I should try, it would be nice if you could help me!

Note: I am using [osixia/openldap](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap), which *should* use OpenLDAP 2.4.44

Comment: Okay, I could resolve the problem after some digging around. For some reason, my install does not handle SSHA-256 or SSHA-512 passwords correctly, but SSHA does work, so I'm using that now!